# How to extract Version number from the web content using preg_match php

Tags: php, regex

I would like to extract the version number from the url content. i tried to extract info using curl_exec. but unable to get the preg_match to get the exact info.

Code i tried is

```
function getVersionFromurl(string $url)
{
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    $content = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    $rx = preg_match("(\"version\" (\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+))", $content, $matches);
    echo $matches[1];
}

$url = 'https://www.foxitsoftware.com/downloads/downloadForm.php?retJson=1&product=Foxit-Reader&platform=Mac-OS-X';
$val = getVersionFromurl($url);
```

here the content came as

"{"package_info":{"language":["English","French","German","Italian","Spanish"],"type":["pkg"],"version":["3.4.0.1012","2.1.0804","2.0.0625","1.1.1.0301","1.1.0.0128"],"size":"139.13MB","release":"10/15/19","os":"","down":"/pub/foxit/reader/desktop/mac/3.x/3.4/ML/FoxitReader340.setup.pkg","mirror":"","manual":"","big_version":"3.x"}}1"

How to extract 3.4.0.1012 from the content.
the preg_matcxh i tried gives me error. how to write the preg_match regular expression.

Please any help.

Comment: Your pattern could look like `"version":\["(\d+(?:\.\d+){3})"` See https://regex101.com/r/wen7ya/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

better to convert string to JSON object, and get version value from there

```
function getVersionFromurl(string $url)
{
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    $content = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    $contentObj = json_decode($content);
    echo $contentObj.package_info.version[0];
}

$url = 'https://www.foxitsoftware.com/downloads/downloadForm.php?retJson=1&product=Foxit-Reader&platform=Mac-OS-X';
$val = getVersionFromurl($url);
```

Notice this conversion from string into object, and get first element of version array

```
$contentObj = json_decode($content);
echo $contentObj.package_info.version[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

In your pattern you are not accounting for this part `:\["` after `"version"`
You are also using 2 capturing groups, so `$matches[1]` would then contain the whole match and `$matches[2]` would contain your value.

But instead, you can use 1 capturing group.

```
"version":\["(\d+(?:\.\d+){3})"
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wen7ya/1/) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/VrPao)

```
preg_match('~"version":\["(\d+(?:\.\d+){3})"~', $content, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

Output

```
3.4.0.1012
```

**Note** that you don't have to escape the double quotes and that you have to use [delimiters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) for the pattern.

Comment: i get the error 'PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /workspace/Main.php on line 8" .  for  "echo $matches[1];"   it looks like preg_match returned nothing.

Comment: Are you sure you have the same payload? What does the string look like?